# diophantine equation $x(x^2-x)+y(y^2-y)=2xy$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

OK so I accidentally posted a wrong equation in my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458867/integer-solutions-for-xx-1yy-1-xy) and I didn't realize it after it was solved. Hope it helped someone and sorry. This is the more challenging one I wanted to solve.

Comment: why don't you provide a link to your referred question? It'll be easier for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

$x^3+y^3-(x+y)^2=(x+y)(x^2+y^2-xy-x-y)$

Where the second part has already been discussed in your last question([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458867/)).

Answer (score -2):

If $x=y$,
this becomes
$x(x^2-x) = x^2$.
A solution is $x = 0$.
If $x \ne 0$,
$x^2-x = x$
or $x=2$.

If $x > y > 0$,
$x(x^2-x) < 2x^2$
or $x^2-x < 2x$
or $x < 3$.

This then reduces to
trying $x = 2$, $y=1$
which works.

Comment: $x^2-x=x$ for x different than 0?

Comment: Why are you assuming they must be positive?

Comment: Diophantine equations usually look for positive integer solutions.